# Let $f (x)= x^7 -105x + 12$ then which of the following options is correct?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $f (x)= x^7  - 105 x +12$ then
>
> 1. $f (x)$ is reducible over $ \mathbb {Q} $
> 2. There exists an integer $m$ such that $f (m)=105$
> 3. There exists an integer $m$ such that $f (m)=2$
> 4. $f (m)$ is not a prime number for any integer  $m$

By Eisenstein 1 option is false.  For option 2, if  possible  let  there  be   an   integer   such   that   $f (m)=105$   then

$ m^7  - 105 m +12= 105$ implies $ m^7  -105 m -93=0$,  $m$ can be  $1, -1, 3, -3, 31, -31, 93, -93$  so clearly  option 2  is  false   and  in a  similar  way  option   3   is  also false. I   have  no  idea  about   option  4.

So my request  is  to check  whether  my reasoning  of  option 1, 2  and  3  are alright  and   to give  me  a  hint  for   option  4.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $f(x)$ is clearly even for all integer $x$. Hence it is a prime only if it equals $2$.

Comment: Do you know Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: My apology, But I didn't understand how did you say so easily that f (x) is even for all integer x

Comment: yes sir I know Eisenstein criterion

Comment: Expanding @Coolwater's hint, consider the function $f(x)-2$ and note that $5$ divides $10$ and $105$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint for 4). Note that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $x\in\mathbb{Z}$,  $x^n\equiv x \pmod{2}$, therefore 
$$f(x)=x^7-105x+12\equiv x-x+0=0\pmod{2}$$ 
which means that for any integer $x$, $f(x)$ is divisible by $2$.

Since $2$ is the only even prime it remains to show that there is no integer $x$ such that $f(x)=2$. That is, the equation 
$$x^7-105x+10=0$$
has no integer solution.  Can you take it from here? Recall the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

P.S. BTW option 2 is false because 105 is odd.

Comment: Thank you for explaining option 4 so kindly. ...but  I  applied rational root test theorem on option 3 and the possible roots are $ 1, -1, 2, -2, 5, -5, 10, -10 $ I couldn't understand  why it is not enough to check on that possible roots?  will you please explain that?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari Sorry, you are right I misread your your attempt.

Comment: It's alright thank you so much sir

Answer (score 2):

Look at $f(x)$ modulo $2$.
$$x^7-105x+12 \equiv x^7-x \pmod{2}$$
This polynomial evaluates $0$ for $x\equiv 0$ and for $x \equiv 1$: this suffices to prove that $f(x)$ is always divisible by $2$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire This was already showed in 3.